# I Need to make a icon and some graphics for my game including characters in 2d how do i do tihs

Tags: python, character, 2d, sprite

I am making a space themed game it needs a bunch of diffrent skins for the same template of 2 rocket i also need a home screen and settings opptions i need to do this for a school project in python any help would be appreaiated

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask questions here. Also, stackoverflow is not meant to be a homework solving site. It is your responsibility to come up with a solution and try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflow is used to help solve problems with code mostly,
Make the skins in something like Gimp, Photoshop,paint or some other art program and add them to a directory.

Try working on it and any issues you run into don't hesitate to bring it here and ask!

All users are happy to help you with any issues, but we aren't here to do class work/ school projects for you!